# App crash crash if button clicked at start but not if clicked after Seekbar moved

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

This is my first question but as a learner, I read often to find solutions to problems.
So, I am following a tutorial on Android using Java. The challenge is creating a Timer to cook an egg. 
I was able to manage everything so far:
- created a `seekBar` to set the time;
- moving the `seekBar` edit the TextView to show the timer;
- created a button to start and stop the timer `(button change when pressed from start to stop and another way round)`.

Now I realize that I have a little bug. If I open the app, scrub the SeekBar and then press the button, everything works. If I press the button as soon the app is open, crash.

Here the error messages:

```
01-27 14:50:41.011 20206-20206/com.example.yuri.eggtimer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.yuri.eggtimer, PID: 20206
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.CountDownTimer android.os.CountDownTimer.start()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.yuri.eggtimer.MainActivity$override.startTimer(MainActivity.java:26)
        at com.example.yuri.eggtimer.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(Unknown Source:95)
        at com.example.yuri.eggtimer.MainActivity.startTimer(MainActivity.java:0)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Here the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//Button startStop = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
//Creating a countDownTimer variable
CountDownTimer count;
// Creating a boolean variable to check if the timer is running.
boolean isRunning = false;


//Button method for start and stop
public void startTimer(View view) {
    Log.i("info","Button pressed");
    if (!isRunning){
        final Button startStop = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        count.start();
        startStop.setText("Stop");
        isRunning = true;
    }else{
        final Button startStop = findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        count.cancel();
        startStop.setText("Start");
        isRunning = false;

    }

}



public void updateClock(int progress){
    int time=progress/1000;
    int minutes = Math.round(time/60);
    int seconds = time%60;
    TextView clock = findViewById(R.id.clockTextView);
    clock.setText(minutes+":"+seconds);
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Setting variable for max time and starting time
    int max = 300;
    final int[] startingPosition = {30};


    //Calling the seekbar and setting the max and starting point
    SeekBar timer = findViewById(R.id.eggSeekBar);
    timer.setMax(max*1000);
    timer.setProgress(startingPosition[0] *1000);
    //creating Long type for countDownTimer
    final Long[] timerProgress = {new Long(timer.getProgress())};

    //set the starting clock
    updateClock(startingPosition[0]*1000);


    timer.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            timerProgress[0] = Long.valueOf(progress);
            updateClock(progress);

            count = new CountDownTimer(timerProgress[0],1000){
                public void onTick(long secondLeft){
                    Long seconds = secondLeft;
                    int sec = seconds.intValue();
                    updateClock(sec);

                    Log.i("Second left", String.valueOf(secondLeft/1000));
                }

                public void onFinish(){
                    Log.i("Info","We are done!");

                }

            };


        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

I tried the button only with a log, and there is no problem. I noticed that the problem is when I want to start the countdown (in my case called count). 
If in the method `starttimer` I just put count.start(), if I click as soon the app starts it to crash. So I got that the problem should be somewhere in the countdown, but I do not understand why it works if I scrub the `seekBar` first.

Thanks, everyone will take the time to read and/or answer this.

Comment: Why you made your button as `final`? `final Button startStop = findViewById(R.id.startButton);` ?

Comment: post up xml too

Comment: @Vault23 Before the button was outside the if-else statement and android studio was asking me to make it final to access it. I took it of now. Thanks.

Comment: @Wini i sort the problem initializing the CountDownTime outside the seekBar in the onCreate method as suggested by Zholot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just the NPE when calling `count.start()` on the not initialized CountDownTimer.
Simply add a default time as a constant and initialize your `count` with this in onCreate :)

Your problem is that you initialize it in the seekBarChange-callback only.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That sort it out!!! Now it is working properly!

Comment: @GrisoFandango mark this answer as best then